# Angular 2 alternative to subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have the following code:

> this.firebase.database.list('/schedule',{query: {orderByChild:
>   'user_day',equalTo: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day }})
>           .subscribe(data => {

Is there an alternative to subscribe that I can you? Because I know it's realtime and it messes up my code.

What I'm trying to do is, if a key exists in db I need to know If I need to update or insert, but with my current code, it breaks after 2-3 updates, and I think it's because of subscribe.

Full code

```
var schedule = this.firebase.database.list('/schedule');

this.firebase.database.list('/schedule',{query: {orderByChild: 'user_day',equalTo: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day }})
.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.length == 0){
        //insert
        schedule.push({from : from, to : to, user_id : this.currentUser.uid, user_day: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day,day : day});
    }else{
        //update
        schedule.update(data[0].$key,{from : from, to : to});
        console.log(from,to);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is it breaking? You should unsubscribe when you destroy the component (ngOnDestroy) so that you don't wind up with multiple subscriptions accumulating on subsequent reloads.

Comment: I have an (ionChange)="hoursSelect(work_day,child,checkbox)" event that executes the code, and after 3 changes, it consumes 800mb ram the tab, so I'm guessing is because of the subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unusual errors on subsequent loading of a component which includes an Observable / Subscribe may be the a result of subscribing to Observables and not unsubscribing when you destroy the component, so the subscription persists and when the component loads again, the Observable responds multiple times to the component request. These subscriptions accumulate.

To prevent this, and to prevent memory leaking, you should unsubscribe to the Observable when you destroy each component.

Add these imports to your component

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Add this in your class - I usually do this above the constructor.

```
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>()
```

Add an ngOnDestroy function

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

And then add this immediately before your .subscribe (you should use this exact syntax before every .subscribe in components with multiples).

```
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
```

So in your case, it would look like this.

```
this.firebase.database.list('/schedule',{query: {orderByChild: 'user_day',equalTo: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day }})
.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.length == 0){
        //insert
        schedule.push({from : from, to : to, user_id : this.currentUser.uid, user_day: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day,day : day});
    }else{
        //update
        schedule.update(data[0].$key,{from : from, to : to});
        console.log(from,to);
    }
});
```

So what happens is the subscribe will remain active until you navigate away from the component, at which point ngOnDestroy fires which unsubscribes from the Observable cleanly.

See if that resolves the problems you're having after multiple updates.

Observables are a great feature, and while there are some odd issues (like this one) that can be frustrating at first, once you've got them sorted you'll likely learn to love them.

Based on your console log, it looks like you're getting a constant stream of data, in which case you can use the take(x) operator to take a single value from the Observable.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'
```

And then add `.take(1)` before the .subscribe

So in your case, it would look like this.

```
this.firebase.database.list('/schedule',{query: {orderByChild: 'user_day',equalTo: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day }})
.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
.take(1)
.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.length == 0){
        //insert
        schedule.push({from : from, to : to, user_id : this.currentUser.uid, user_day: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+day,day : day});
    }else{
        //update
        schedule.update(data[0].$key,{from : from, to : to});
        console.log(from,to);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Amazing! But something weird it's happening still, look at the console log, https://screencast.com/t/oT6qwQ37jh

Comment: I'm wondering if taking one value instead of a stream might solve that. import 'rxjs/add/operator/take' and then add .take(1) before the .subscribe - see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Yes take(1) worked Sir!, update your answer so I can accept it.